# how to pass over a function if not called upon

Tags: python, class

how can i pass over a function if it is not called upon. For example, user doesn't want soap so i want to skip over the soap function and go to the drying function and then end the program. I want the output to be 6.

```
class WashHandler(object):

    def main_wash(self):
        self.cost = (self.cost + 5)
        user_input = input("yes or no, Do you want soap added?")
        if user_input == no:
            drying_addition()

    def soap_addition(self):
        self.cost = (self.cost + 2)

    def drying_addition(self):
        self.cost = (self.cost + 1)

    def finish(self):
        print("Your total is " self.cost)


handler = WashHandler()
handler.main_wash()
handler.soap_addition()
handler.drying_addition()
handler.finish()
```

Comment: you have a **soad_addition()** though I believe it's a typo :)

Comment: Just ask the user what they want and then give it to them .i,e call the appropriate methods

Comment: also it is `self.drying_addition()`,self.cost and in is not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit of a slippery slope in that you're presenting us with code where `WashHandler`'s responsibilities are being determined from the outside. This is not a good way to organize your code as it breaks encapsulation. It would be more preferable if the logic in this case were inside of `WashHandler`, like so:

```
class WashHandler(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.cost = 0

    def main_wash(self):
        self.cost += 5
        user_input = input("yes or no, Do you want soap added?")

        if user_input == "yes":
            self.soap_addition()
        
        self.drying_addition()
        self.finish()

    def soap_addition(self):
        self.cost += 2

    def drying_addition(self):
        self.cost += 1

    def finish(self):
        print("Your total is ", str(self.cost))
```

Whichever client calls `WashHandler` doesn't really *need* to know anything about how or by what logic the process of 'washing' is conducted. That is up to `WashHandler` alone to figure out.

```
handler = WashHandler()
handler.main_wash()
```

As you see, it only needs to be told *what to do*, but not *how*. The method `main_wash` takes care of the logic and executes all the relevant statements in their correct order.

#### Disclaimer:

Just to be clear, I added in some of the modifications by @Padraic (`self.cost+=` and initialization in `__init__` for completeness sake, otherwise it wouldn't work).